# "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown" while using xmlserializer

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the following code to get an xml string.

```
public static string ToXMLString(object obj, string nodeName)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = default(XmlSerializer);
    string xml = string.Empty;
    StreamReader r = default(StreamReader);
    try
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(m, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true }))
                {
                    // Don't include XML namespace
                    XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlnsEmpty = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                    xmlnsEmpty.Add("", "");
                    if (xmlSerializer == null)
                        xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), new XmlRootAttribute(nodeName));
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj, xmlnsEmpty);

                    m.Flush();
                    m.Position = 0;

                    r = new StreamReader(m);
                    xml = r.ReadToEnd();
                    xmlSerializer = null;
                }
            }
        }

        return xml;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        r.Close();
        r.Dispose();
    }
    //XmlSerializer xmlSerializer;

}
```

I have a loop that runs using the method and after some time i get an out of memory exception as below:

What might the cause of the exception? Is using statement really disposing streams? Or what other alternative can i use?

Comment: it won't affect the code, but there's no benefit declaring those variables at the top, nor assigning `xmlSerializer` to `null` at the end; I'd just declare in-line, i.e. `var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(...);`. You aren't disposing the reader, but that won't be killing you here. Actually, you could write to a `StringBuilder` if you just want the string - avoids messing with the `Stream`...

Comment: Can we see the object model that you are serializing? I *suspect* this is related to the model - something like a cyclic reference (that is evading the inbuilt detection - not impossible to do), or something similar

Comment: `using` calls `IDisposable.Dispose()` when exiting the using block. So that part of your code is fine.

Comment: This isn't related to the OOM error, but: here's a slightly refactored and more direct version of the same code: http://pastie.org/3248365

Comment: Wondering why you use the `default(StreamReader)` syntax twice here? ALSO, you are overwriting `r` without disposing the prior instance. It will go out of scope and be GC'd anyway but not as quickly as explicit disposal.

Comment: @Kevin that is unrelated - it just means "null"; not very clear, but not a problem. There is only one reader (it isn't overwritten), although it also isn't disposed - but... again, not the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would expect the issue here is assembly saturation. `XmlSerializer` works by generating an assembly on the fly; if you use the `XmlSerializer(Type)` constructor, it caches it and looks it up; but for **any other constructor** it doesn't. And assemblies can't (usually) by unloaded. So you just get more and more and more assemblies eating your memory. You will need to cache the serializer if you are running this in a loop:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // the loop here is from your comment
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { ToXMLString("test", string.Format("test")); Console.WriteLine(i); }
    }

    // why is this Hashtable? due to the threading semantics!
    private static readonly Hashtable serializerCache = new Hashtable();

    public static string ToXMLString(object obj, string nodeName)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        var cacheKey = new { Type = type, Name = nodeName };
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = (XmlSerializer)serializerCache[cacheKey];
        if (xmlSerializer == null)
        {
            lock (serializerCache)
            { // double-checked
                xmlSerializer = (XmlSerializer)serializerCache[cacheKey];
                if (xmlSerializer == null)
                {
                    xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type, new XmlRootAttribute(nodeName));
                    serializerCache.Add(cacheKey, xmlSerializer);
                }
            }
        }
        try
        {

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw,
                new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true }))
            {
                // Don't include XML namespace
                XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlnsEmpty = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                xmlnsEmpty.Add("", "");
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj, xmlnsEmpty);
            }
            return sw.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                t.ToXMLString("test", string.Format ( "test" ));

               Console.WriteLine(i );
               GC.Collect();
            }

Comment: @user1010863 I have no idea how to interpret that comment... - also, `string.Format("test")` - just.... why?

Comment: Thats how i am using the method from my application. I am still confused what could be making the large use of memory. Its a loop that runs calling the function. Looking at the task manager the physical memory for devenv keeps on increasing upto to around 83% where i get the exception.

Comment: @user1010863 is that with? or without? the assembly caching that I suggested?

Comment: With the caching now you suggested, its behaving the same

Comment: @user1010863 wait... is it "devenv" that is growing? or the actual exe? if "devenv", it could just be the IDE - perhaps intellitrace. Try it outside the debugger (ctrl+f5). I have it running (with my code, as above) in a loop, and the memory is rock solid; no growth.

Comment: @user1010863 for info, doing the same without the caching, and it is a: really really slow, and b: growing memory (it has only got to a few hundred, and is using more memory that the code with assembly caching was using for 500k iterations - and growing). With the assembly caching enabled, my working set, at 4,350,000 iterations, is 2644k and holding like a rock.

Comment: @user1010863 here's the full thing (see edit); as a side note, if I take out the `GC.Collect()`, it grows a **little**, but not much - currently at 6832k (memory) after 5.5M+ iterations, and holding pretty steady

Comment: Thanks alot for your sample. Am now testing it and seem to work fine

Answer (score 5):

The problem here may not be this code per-se, but what you are doing with the generated string outside this method.

Depending on what you are serializing, it is likely this gives rise to many large strings. If you are holding onto these strings as you go round your loop you are ikely to be consuming larger and larger amounts of memory. To make things worse, even though the *absolute* amount of memory being used may not be huge, it is highly likely that these large strings are causing memory fragmentation - the GC may not be able to allocate a contiguous block of memory for the next string.

In the CLR - large objects (large being something around 85KB I think) are not allocated to the usual GC generations; instead they go in the Large Object Heap. This heap is never compacted (unless this has changed in .Net 4 in which case I may not know it). The implication of this is that if you have lots of strings allocated and being held onto, there ends up with fewer and fewer blocks of contiguous free space that are large enough to allocate your next string This is because there is no process to compact the allocated blocks together when other blocks of memory are freed. This, quite easily, can give rise to out-of-memory exceptions, as described above, when doing exactly this sort of operation.

[This](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/) article gives a good overview of the "dangers" and considerations of the Large Object Heap.

What are you doing with the strings returned by this method, and how big are the strings being generated?

Comment: From what I have read, the Large Object Heap is now compacted with .Net 4.5 (and higher)