# Purpose and use of 'default' keyword in non-generics

Tags: c#

[A recent question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999159) made use of the `default` keyword in non-generic code that interests me:

```
StreamReader r = default(StreamReader);
```

What is the purpose served here? How is this different from:

```
StreamReader r;
```

Both statements define `r`. In 'SLaks' answer below, he clarifies that the use of `default` additionally sets `r` to `null`, but that could be done explicitly by just using `null`. Is this a style issue, or is there some utility served?

I have used [`default` in generic code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) (and, of course, [in `switch` statement blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)) but do not understand it's purpose in this usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's different from `StreamReader r;` in that it assigns the variable.
It's (completely) identical to `StreamReader r = null;`.

For reference types, `default(T)` compiles to `null`.
For value types, `default(T)` compiles to `new T()`.

C#'s `default(T)` keyword [is actually equivalent to VB.Net's `Nothing` keyword](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/nothing-vs-null.html).

Comment: Right. I got that far reading elsewhere. What is the purpose of writing `null` in this verbose manner?

Comment: @KevinR: None.  They compile identically.

Comment: So, you are saying this is just a style choice. Except that I did read elsewhere that auto-generated code templates might output code like this, but I would presume it was hand-written in the S.O. question I linked to (where I saw this code). Any guess why one would prefer such a style? It seems an overly explicit way to just say `null`.

Comment: Yes, and a dumb choice, IMHO.  This can be useful for code generators if the generator doesn't know whether a type is a struct or not.

Comment: >"and a dumb choice" -- THANK YOU. I have to agree. And I personally prefer explicitness when coding. This smells like obfuscation to me for hand-written code, unless there is some justification.

Comment: It may have been copied from auto-generated code by someone who didn't understand it.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `default(T)` produces the default value for a type generic or not.  For reference types it will be `null` and for value types it will be a 0 initialization.  While it's most useful in generic code it's still usable, if often a bit verbose, in regular code.

For example.  The following groups of lines are all equivalent

```
StreamReader r = null;
StreamReader r = default(StreamReader);
var r = default(StreamReader);

int i = 0;
int i = default(int);
var i = default(int);
```

Comment: Same comment as to SLaks below-- You are saying this is just a style choice? I did read elsewhere that auto-generated code templates might output code like this, but I would presume it was hand-written in the S.O. question I linked to (where I saw this code). Any reasoning why one would prefer such a style? It seems an overly explicit way to just say `null`.

Comment: @KevinP.Rice There is certainly a case to be made for code generators choosing this as it's more universal. But at it's core it's a style choice (one you wouldn't ever catch me doing though).

Answer (score 0):

var r = default(StreamReader); 
might make some sense, especially if you were trying to develop a coding habit.
Other than that the only advantage I could see, is if at some point in the future  StreamReader's default might no longer be null, which seems unlikely.....

Comment: That's not just unlikely; it will **never** happen.

Comment: This is IT. You'll never use up 640k. Change is  given. BeSides I was alluding to the thinking behind the foolishness.